# Can I do this with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

Can I do this in LINQ, specifically the Split function on the passed in string?

```
var lstValues = from objValue in value.Split('[')
                where objValue != ""
                select objValue;
```

Comment: If the LINQ code you've shown isn't just a trivial example, you could just use the Split overload that excepts an additional enum parameter (called `StringSplitOptions` i think), that you can set to ignore empty strings.

Comment: Since `string.Split()` returns an array of strings, that ought to work.

Answer (score 9):

Looks fine, but this also looks like you just remove empty entries, you could just use the `StringSplitOptions` for that:

```
value.Split(new char[]{'['}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```